how do i make a form submission permanent in my django project?
in my django project
models.py =
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class User(AbstractUser):
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic/')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=160, blank=True, null=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers/', blank=True)
    whatsapp = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            "username": self.username,
            "profile_pic": self.profile_pic.url,
            "first_name": self.first_name,
            "last_name": self.last_name
        }

class Post(models.Model):
    creater = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    content_text = models.TextField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    content_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/', blank=True)
    likers = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True , related_name='likes')
    savers = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True , related_name='saved')
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Post ID: {self.id} (creater: {self.creater})"

    def img_url(self):
        return self.content_image.url

    def append(self, name, value):
        self.name = value

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    commenter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='commenters')
    comment_content = models.TextField(max_length=90)
    comment_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Post: {self.post} | Commenter: {self.commenter}"

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "commenter": self.commenter.serialize(),
            "body": self.comment_content,
            "timestamp": self.comment_time.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p")
        }
    
class Follower(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followers')
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='following')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"User: {self.user}"
        

views.py =
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
import json

from .models import *


def index(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    if page_number == None:
        page_number = 1
    posts = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    followings = []
    suggestions = []
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        followings = Follower.objects.filter(followers=request.user).values_list('user', flat=True)
        suggestions = User.objects.exclude(pk__in=followings).exclude(username=request.user.username).order_by("?")[:6]
    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "posts": posts,
        "suggestions": suggestions,
        "page": "all_posts",
        'profile': False
    })


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "network/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "network/login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        fname = request.POST["firstname"]
        lname = request.POST["lastname"]
        profile = request.FILES.get("profile")
        print(f"--------------------------Profile: {profile}----------------------------")
        cover = request.FILES.get('cover')
        print(f"--------------------------Cover: {cover}----------------------------")

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.first_name = fname
            user.last_name = lname
            if profile is not None:
                user.profile_pic = profile
            else:
                user.profile_pic = "profile_pic/no_pic.png"
            user.cover = cover           
            user.save()
            Follower.objects.create(user=user)
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "network/register.html")



def profile(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    all_posts = Post.objects.filter(creater=user).order_by('-date_created')
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    if page_number == None:
        page_number = 1
    posts = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    followings = []
    suggestions = []
    follower = False
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        followings = Follower.objects.filter(followers=request.user).values_list('user', flat=True)
        suggestions = User.objects.exclude(pk__in=followings).exclude(username=request.user.username).order_by("?")[:6]

        if request.user in Follower.objects.get(user=user).followers.all():
            follower = True
    
    follower_count = Follower.objects.get(user=user).followers.all().count()
    following_count = Follower.objects.filter(followers=user).count()
    return render(request, 'network/profile.html', {
        "username": user,
        "posts": posts,
        "posts_count": all_posts.count(),
        "suggestions": suggestions,
        "page": "profile",
        "is_follower": follower,
        "follower_count": follower_count,
        "following_count": following_count,
        "email": user.email,
    })

def following(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        following_user = Follower.objects.filter(followers=request.user).values('user')
        all_posts = Post.objects.filter(creater__in=following_user).order_by('-date_created')
        paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 10)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        if page_number == None:
            page_number = 1
        posts = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        followings = Follower.objects.filter(followers=request.user).values_list('user', flat=True)
        suggestions = User.objects.exclude(pk__in=followings).exclude(username=request.user.username).order_by("?")[:6]
        return render(request, "network/index.html", {
            "posts": posts,
            "suggestions": suggestions,
            "page": "following"
        })
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

def saved(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        all_posts = Post.objects.filter(savers=request.user).order_by('-date_created')

        paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 10)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        if page_number == None:
            page_number = 1
        posts = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        followings = Follower.objects.filter(followers=request.user).values_list('user', flat=True)
        suggestions = User.objects.exclude(pk__in=followings).exclude(username=request.user.username).order_by("?")[:6]
        return render(request, "network/index.html", {
            "posts": posts,
            "suggestions": suggestions,
            "page": "saved"
        })
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
        


@login_required
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST.get('text')
        pic = request.FILES.get('picture')
        try:
            post = Post.objects.create(creater=request.user, content_text=text, content_image=pic)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(e)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Method must be 'POST'")

@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST.get('text')
        pic = request.FILES.get('picture')
        img_chg = request.POST.get('img_change')
        post_id = request.POST.get('id')
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        try:
            post.content_text = text
            if img_chg != 'false':
                post.content_image = pic
            post.save()
            
            if(post.content_text):
                post_text = post.content_text
            else:
                post_text = False
            if(post.content_image):
                post_image = post.img_url()
            else:
                post_image = False
            
            return JsonResponse({
                "success": True,
                "text": post_text,
                "picture": post_image
            })
        except Exception as e:
            print('-----------------------------------------------')
            print(e)
            print('-----------------------------------------------')
            return JsonResponse({
                "success": False
            })
    else:
            return HttpResponse("Method must be 'POST'")

@csrf_exempt
def like_post(request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
            print(post)
            try:
                post.likers.add(request.user)
                post.save()
                return HttpResponse(status=204)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(e)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Method must be 'PUT'")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

@csrf_exempt
def unlike_post(request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
            print(post)
            try:
                post.likers.remove(request.user)
                post.save()
                return HttpResponse(status=204)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(e)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Method must be 'PUT'")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

@csrf_exempt
def save_post(request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
            print(post)
            try:
                post.savers.add(request.user)
                post.save()
                return HttpResponse(status=204)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(e)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Method must be 'PUT'")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

@csrf_exempt
def unsave_post(request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
            print(post)
            try:
                post.savers.remove(request.user)
                post.save()
                return HttpResponse(status=204)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(e)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Method must be 'PUT'")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

@csrf_exempt
def follow(request, username):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            print(f".....................User: {user}......................")
            print(f".....................Follower: {request.user}......................")
            try:
                (follower, create) = Follower.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                follower.followers.add(request.user)
                follower.save()
                return HttpResponse(status=204)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(e)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Method must be 'PUT'")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

@csrf_exempt
def unfollow(request, username):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            print(f".....................User: {user}......................")
            print(f".....................Unfollower: {request.user}......................")
            try:
                follower = Follower.objects.get(user=user)
                follower.followers.remove(request.user)
                follower.save()
                return HttpResponse(status=204)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(e)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Method must be 'PUT'")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))


@csrf_exempt
def comment(request, post_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            comment = data.get('comment_text')
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            try:
                newcomment = Comment.objects.create(post=post,commenter=request.user,comment_content=comment)
                post.comment_count += 1
                post.save()
                print(newcomment.serialize())
                return JsonResponse([newcomment.serialize()], safe=False, status=201)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(e)
    
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
        comments = comments.order_by('-comment_time').all()
        return JsonResponse([comment.serialize() for comment in comments], safe=False)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

@csrf_exempt
def delete_post(request, post_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            if request.user == post.creater:
                try:
                    delet = post.delete()
                    return HttpResponse(status=201)
                except Exception as e:
                    return HttpResponse(e)
            else:
                return HttpResponse(status=404)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Method must be 'PUT'")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))


urls.py =

from django.urls import path

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("home", views.index, name="index"),
    path("n/login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("n/logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("n/register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("<str:username>", views.profile, name='profile'),
    path("n/following", views.following, name='following'),
    path("n/saved", views.saved, name="saved"),
    path("n/createpost", views.create_post, name="createpost"),
    path("n/post/<int:id>/like", views.like_post, name="likepost"),
    path("n/post/<int:id>/unlike", views.unlike_post, name="unlikepost"),
    path("n/post/<int:id>/save", views.save_post, name="savepost"),
    path("n/post/<int:id>/unsave", views.unsave_post, name="unsavepost"),
    path("n/post/<int:post_id>/comments", views.comment, name="comments"),
    path("n/post/<int:post_id>/write_comment",views.comment, name="writecomment"),
    path("n/post/<int:post_id>/delete", views.delete_post, name="deletepost"),
    path("<str:username>/follow", views.follow, name="followuser"),
    path("<str:username>/unfollow", views.unfollow, name="unfollowuser"),
    path("n/post/<int:post_id>/edit", views.edit_post, name="editpost")
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)



the html file is inside a folder named network which is inside the templates folder
profile.html=
{% extends 'network/index.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block profile %}
    <div class="profile-view" data-user="{{username.username}}">
       
        <div class="mbs-pec" id="mbs-pec" >
          
            <form method="POST" class="mbs-pecc" style="display: block;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div id="mbs-ec" class="mbs-ec">
                    <div id="mbs-ecc" class="mbs-ecc1">
                        <p>cover image</p>
                        <div class="c-image" style="background-image: url(/media/{{username.cover}})"></div>
                        <input type="file" name="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div id="mbs-ecc" class="mbs-ecc2">
                        <p>profile image</p>
                        <div class="p-image" style="background-image: url(/media/{{username.profile_pic}})"></div>
                        <input type="file" name="profile_pic">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>First Name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{username.first_name}}">
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Last Name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{username.last_name}}">
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Username</p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="{{username.username}}">
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Bio</p>
                    <input type="text" name="bio" value="{{username.bio}}">
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Email</p>
                    <input type="email" name="email a" value="{{username.email}}">
                </div>
                
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Whatsapp</p>
                    <input type="text" name="whatsapp" value="{{username.whatsapp}}">
                </div>
               
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb " >
                    <button class="mbs-done btn btn-outline-success" id="mbs-done">Done</button>
                    <button class="mbs-close btn btn-outline-success" id="mbs-close">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
        
       
        <div class="cover-image" style="background-image: url(/media/{{username.cover}})"></div>
        <div class="profile-image" style="background-image: url(/media/{{username.profile_pic}})"></div>
        <div class="profile-details">
            <div>
                {% if user.username == username.username %}
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success float-right" id="edit-profile-btn">Edit Profile</button>
                {% elif is_follower %}
                    <button class="btn btn-success float-right" onclick="unfollow_user(this,'{{username.username}}','edit_page')" id="following-btn">Following</button>
                {% else %}
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success float-right" onclick="follow_user(this,'{{username.username}}','edit_page')" id="follow-btn">Follow</button>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="details-data">
                <h5>{{username.first_name}} {{username.last_name}}</h5>
                <div class="grey">@{{username.username}}</div>
                <div class="whatsapp">
                    {% if username.whatsapp is not None %}
                        <a href="https://wa.me/{{username.whatsapp}}" target="_blank">Whatsapp</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="bio">
                    {% if username.bio is not None %}
                        {{username.bio}}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="grey" style="padding: 8px 0px;">
                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar3" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 0H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zM1 3.857C1 3.384 1.448 3 2 3h12c.552 0 1 .384 1 .857v10.286c0 .473-.448.857-1 .857H2c-.552 0-1-.384-1-.857V3.857z"/>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.5 7a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm3 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm3 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm-9 3a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm3 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm3 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm3 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm-9 3a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm3 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm3 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z"/>
                    </svg>
                    &nbsp;Joined {{username.date_joined | date:"F Y"}}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <strong>
                        {{posts_count}}
                    </strong>
                    &nbsp;<span class="grey">Posts</span>
                    &ensp;
                    <a href="#">
                        <strong id="following__count">{{following_count | default:0}}</strong>&nbsp;<span class="grey">Following</span>
                    </a>
                    &ensp;
                    <a href="#">
                        <strong id="follower__count">{{follower_count | default:0}}</strong>&nbsp;<span class="grey">Followers</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block emptyprofile %}
    <center>
        <br>
        <strong style="font-size: 1.2em;">@{{username}} hasn't posted</strong>
        <div class="grey" style="font-size: .9em;">When they do, their posts will show up here.</div>
    </center>
{% endblock %}

focus on this part of the code
<div class="mbs-pec" id="mbs-pec" >
          
            <form method="POST" class="mbs-pecc" style="display: block;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div id="mbs-ec" class="mbs-ec">
                    <div id="mbs-ecc" class="mbs-ecc1">
                        <p>cover image</p>
                        <div class="c-image" style="background-image: url(/media/{{username.cover}})"></div>
                        <input type="file" name="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div id="mbs-ecc" class="mbs-ecc2">
                        <p>profile image</p>
                        <div class="p-image" style="background-image: url(/media/{{username.profile_pic}})"></div>
                        <input type="file" name="profile_pic">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>First Name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{username.first_name}}">
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Last Name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{username.last_name}}">
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Username</p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="{{username.username}}">
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Bio</p>
                    <input type="text" name="bio" value="{{username.bio}}">
                </div>
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Email</p>
                    <input type="email" name="email a" value="{{username.email}}">
                </div>
                
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb a">
                    <p>Whatsapp</p>
                    <input type="text" name="whatsapp" value="{{username.whatsapp}}">
                </div>
               
                <div id="mbs-pecb" class="mbs-pecb " >
                    <button class="mbs-done btn btn-outline-success" id="mbs-done">Done</button>
                    <button class="mbs-close btn btn-outline-success" id="mbs-close">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>

here it is displaying the users first name in {{username.first_name}} last name in {{username.last_name}} user name in {{username.username}} bio in {{username.bio}} email in  {{username.email}} whatsapp in {{username.whatsapp}} profile picture in <div class="p-image" style="background-image: url(/media/{{username.profile_pic}})"></div> and cover picture in <div class="c-image" style="background-image: url(/media/{{username.cover}})"></div> now what i want is that when i update the information in first name, last name, username, bio, email, whatsapp and click on the "Done" button Done it will change the information permanently.
